# How can I reliably convert YYYYMMDDhhmmss<offset> to a date/time?

Tags: sql, datetime, intersystems-cache

I have a data source where the dates come back like this: `20150614140520-0500`

How can I display this better?  It doesn't actually have to be converted technically, this is just for reporting.  Ideally it would output `2015-06-14 2:05 PM (EST)` but I also want the statement to be as simple as possible so the timezone offset and 12hr time are optional.

I tried `CAST ('20150614140520-0500' As Date)` but it returns `null`

I also tried `CAST (LEFT('20150614140520-0500',14) As Date)` as well as some other variants without luck.

Comment: Which DMBS are you using?

Comment: Ah. I didn't know Caché also supported SQL I always thought it was a pure object-oriented DBMS.

Comment: It natively exposes an OO layer as well as a relational layer.  It's neat like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take the first 14 characters, from the example above:

```
print convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(stuff(LEFT('20150614140520-0500',14) , 9, 0, ' '), 12, 0, ':'), 15, 0, ':'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(stuff(datevalue, 9, 0, ' '), 12, 0, ':'), 15, 0, ':')) ConvertedDate
```

As suggested by Dinesh Kumar Rajendran in his blog:
https://rdineshkumar.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-convert-yyyymmddhhmmss-to-datetimedatetime-in-sql-server/