# Convert varchar (eg. 20151125175706+0800) to Datetime in SQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime

How do I convert yyyymmddhhmmss+offset (20151125175706+0800) to datetime format in SQL Server? To something that can be used in datetime comparison to select records entered in table during last one minute.

Im getting this format from OBX segment of the message and I'm saving this as is in a varchar field in table.

I tried to do this(among other things):

```
select cast(convert(varchar,  SUBSTRING(OBXDateTime, 1, 4) + '-' +  
SUBSTRING(OBXDateTime, 5, 2) + '-' + 
SUBSTRING(OBXDateTime, 7, 2) + ' ' +  
SUBSTRING(OBXDateTime, 9, 2) + ':' +
SUBSTRING(OBXDateTime, 11, 2) + ':' +
SUBSTRING(OBXDateTime, 13, 2), 101) as datetime) from ObservationPatInfo
```

This query gives only 522 rows out of 1020 rows in the table and gives as error message saying
"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Kindly help me to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877285/how-can-i-reliably-convert-yyyymmddhhmmssoffset-to-a-date-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @YourDt VARCHAR(100)='20151125175706+0800';
DECLARE @ISO8601_with_TimeZone VARCHAR(100);

--This will use multiple STUFFs to get the separators into your string
SELECT @ISO8601_with_TimeZone = STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@YourDt,18,0,':'),13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,'T'),7,0,'-'),5,0,'-');

--This looks like a properly formatted datetime now: 2015-11-25T17:57:06+08:00
SELECT @ISO8601_with_TimeZone;

--Use DATETIME2 and code 127 to convert ISO8601 with TimeZone
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2,@ISO8601_with_TimeZone,127);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [TRY_CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) to find the bad values:

```
select pi.*
from (select try_convert(ddatetime,
                         (SUBSTRING(OBXDateTime, 1, 4) + '-' +  
                          SUBSTRING(OBXDateTime, 5, 2) + '-' + 
                          SUBSTRING(OBXDateTime, 7, 2) + ' ' +  
                          SUBSTRING(OBXDateTime, 9, 2) + ':' +
                          SUBSTRING(OBXDateTime, 11, 2) + ':' +
                          SUBSTRING(OBXDateTime, 13, 2)
                         ), 101) as datetime) as dte, pi.*
      from ObservationPatInfo pi
     ) pi
where dte is null;
```